# How to Loop between two colors in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble looping between 2 colours of the body forever. It only loops once.

I am using the 'enter' key to trigger the loop and the 'space' key to stop the loop.

```js
const red= () => {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

const blue= () => {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; 
}


const both =  () => {
setTimeout(() => red(), 1000);
 setTimeout(() => blue(), 2000);
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
 if (event.keyCode == 13) {
   setInterval(both(), 3000);
 }

 if (event.keyCode == 32) {
   clearInterval(both());
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Looping Colors</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(red(), 1000);` WRONG.....You are calling red and assigning what it returns to the interval

Comment: So how can I fix it?

Comment: drop the `()`..

Comment: If this is everything you need, why not try to write some css animation, and use JavaScript to toggle that class?

Comment: And you do not have an interval

Comment: This is just a test for something else, I just want to loop two functions back to back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you make in your code currently, is that you:

- you call the function `red` and `blue` and assign the value as the callback for the timeout (which is undefined)
- `both` isn't returning the reference to the timeouts
- `setTimeout` runs exactly once
- `clearInterval` doesn't work on a function reference as you believe it is, but with the result of `setInterval`
- `setTimeout` might be less appropriate, you could use `setInterval` easier

In the below code, I added an extra `toggle` method, that just uses an function property `count` to toggle between `red` and `blue`, `both` returns the value of `setInterval` and assigns it to a function property `interval` to keep track of that interval, and then clears that one

```js
const red= () => {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

const blue= () => {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; 
}

const toggle = () => {
  // when toggle.count doesn't exist, use 0 and increase with 1
  toggle.count = (toggle.count || 0) + 1;
  // when even -> call red() otherwise call blue()
  // you could also verify here what is the backgroundColor
  toggle.count % 2 === 0 ? red() : blue();
}

// returns the result of `setInterval` so the interval can be cleared
const both = () => setInterval( toggle, 1000 );


document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function keyhandler() {
 if (event.keyCode == 13 && !keyhandler.interval) {
   // keep the result of both (setInterval) as reference to the interval
   // mind you, pressing enter twice would leave 1 interval running indefinitely
   // unless you check if interval has a value
   keyhandler.interval = both();
 }

 if (event.keyCode == 32) {
   clearInterval( keyhandler.interval );
   // delete the interval property so you can restart the loop afterwards
   delete keyhandler.interval;
 }
});
```

Comment: Thank You! Can you explain in depth how the toggle function works?

Comment: @MiahTayen I added some comments in the code (and fixed a bug where pressing enter multiple times would have started more intervals that wouldn't be stopable)

Comment: I am sorry to ask this dumb question, what does the % symbol mean in the toggle function.

Comment: @MiahTayen it's the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) or rest after division

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thank You very much for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is `setTimeout` and `setInterval` take an input of a function not the result of a function. Instead of `setTimeout(red(), 1000)` you would write `setTimeout(red, 1000)`

Your second problem is `clearInterval` doesn't take a function. Instead it takes the return value of the `setInterval` function:

```js
var int = setInterval(both, 3000);
clearInterval(int);
```

Full updated code:

```js
const red= () => {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

const blue= () => {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; 
}

const both =  () => {
 setTimeout(red, 1000);
 setTimeout(blue, 2000);
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
 let bothInt;
 if (event.keyCode == 13) {
   bothInt = setInterval(both, 3000);
   bothIntClear = false;
 }
 else if (event.keyCode == 32) {
   clearInterval(bothInt);
 }
});
```

Keep in mind it might take a while for the colors to stop switching because the functions are still in the event queue.

Comment: wouldn't the interval need to be 2000 instead, otherwise there would be an extra 1 second gap between the switches (also you would have the same problem where multiple enters would forget about an existing interval

Comment: Also `bothInt` would be reset on every `keydown` (as it is just a function scoped variable)